# VSFTPD FTP: connect: connection refused

Tags: permissions, ftp, vsftpd

I'm working on FTP server(Ubuntu). According to a video on the Internet I configured it

```
sudo apt-get install vsftpd
```

And joined FTP to localhost (`ftp localhost`) - everything worked.

After a while, I came to a point where it was necessary to add users (`groupadd SEECS mkdir /home/peter chmod 770/home/peter chown root: SEECS /home/peter useradd -g SEECS -d /home/peter useradd -g SEECS -d /home/peter user1` and when I enter command: `psswd user1` it shows me an error about permissions.

Following [another video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uDhZOy1DrDo) I changed my permissions to root permissions. I rebooted FTP and when I tried to connect FTP to localhost,

It shows an error
FTP: connect: connection refused.

How to solve this problem?